# Is it possible to get all member variables in flash(AS3)?

Tags: actionscript-3, reflection, instance-variables, member-variables

I am trying grab all the member variables in AS3, and then foreach one i would like to process it in various ways. I would need the name and then if it is a collection of some type I would like to loop through that collection as well. I am attempting to essentially serialize in a somewhat custom fashion.
Thanks!

Comment: ohhh does describeType do this for me essentially?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to serialize an object, you will definitely want to use JSON.

JSON basically converts objects into strings and also the other way round using an encode()/serialize() and decode()/deserialize() function.

There is a built-in JSON class in AS3, and it's really easy to use.

Once you do something like:

```
var myObject:Object = {};
var myObjectString:String = JSON.serialize(myObject);
```

After getting the string, you can do all your switch logic to manipulate each of your different variables and convert it back into an object via the deserialize() function.

Comment: oh yeaaaa, that would totally get the job done! Although the other part of my program would need to be converted to read json... not such a big deal though.

Answer (score 0):

You could use describeType. That returns information about the object as XML. By default, you can iterate over public properties in objects. You could try something like...

```
// the object to iterate over
var someObj:Object = {};

for(var prop:String in someObj) {
    // check to see if its something you want to iterate over
    if (someObj[prop] is Array) {
        // iterator over the property here
    }
}
```

I hope this answers your question.